# Run an external command within jq to manipulate each values of a particular key

Tags: bash, jq, ripgrep

I have a json like

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tO-qVknlH0PLK9CblQsyd568ZiptdKff/view?usp=share_link",
    "title": "&#8211; Flexibility"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=11_sR8X13lmPcvlT3POfMW3044f3wZdra",
    "title": "&#8211; Pronouns"
  }
]
```

I got it using `curl -Lfs "https://motivatedsisters.com/2019/07/08/arabic-review-sr-rahat-basit/" | rg -o '<li>.*?href="(.*?)".*?</a> (.*?)<\/li>' -r '{"url": "$1", "title": "$2"}' | jq -s '.'`.

I have a command in my machine named `unescape_html`, a python scipt to unescape the html (replace – with appropriate character).

How can I apply this function on each of the titles using `jq`.

For example:

I want to run:

```
unescape_html "&#8211; Flexibility"
unescape_html "&#8211; Pronouns"
```

The expected output is:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tO-qVknlH0PLK9CblQsyd568ZiptdKff/view?usp=share_link",
    "title": "– Flexibility"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=11_sR8X13lmPcvlT3POfMW3044f3wZdra",
    "title": "– Pronouns"
  }
]
```

**Update 1:**

If `jq` doesn't have that feature, then i am also fine that the command is applied on `rg`.

I mean, can i run `unescape_html` on `$2` on the line:

```
rg -o '<li>.*?href="(.*?)".*?</a> (.*?)<\/li>' -r '{"url": "$1", "title": "$2"}'
```

Any other bash approach to solve this problem is also fine. The point is, i need to run `unescape_html` on `title`, so that i get the expected output.

**Update 2:**

The following command:

```
curl -Lfs "https://motivatedsisters.com/2019/07/08/arabic-review-sr-rahat-basit/" | rg -o '<li>.*?href="(.*?)".*?</a> (.*?)<\/li>' -r '{"url": "$1", "title": "$2"}' | jq -s '.' | jq 'map(.title |= @sh "unescape_html \(.)")'
```

gives:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tO-qVknlH0PLK9CblQsyd568ZiptdKff/view?usp=share_link",
    "title": "unescape_html '&#8211; Flexibility'"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=11_sR8X13lmPcvlT3POfMW3044f3wZdra",
    "title": "unescape_html '&#8211; Pronouns'"
  }
]
```

Just not evaluating the commands.

The following command works:

```
curl -Lfs "https://motivatedsisters.com/2019/07/08/arabic-review-sr-rahat-basit/" | rg -o '<li>.*?href="(.*?)".*?</a> (.*?)<\/li>' -r '{"url": "$1", "title": "$2"}' | jq -s '.' | jq 'map(.title |= sub("&#8211;"; "–"))'
```

But it only works for `&#8211;`. It will not work for other reserved characters.

**Update 3:**

The following command:

```
curl -Lfs "https://motivatedsisters.com/2019/07/08/arabic-review-sr-rahat-basit/" | rg -o '<li>.*?href="(.*?)".*?</a> (.*?)<\/li>' -r '{"url": "$1", "title": "$2"}' | jq -s '.' | jq -r '.[] | "unescape_html \(.title | @sh)"' | bash
```

is giving:

```
– Flexibility
– Pronouns
```

So, it is applying the bash function. Now I need to format is so that the urls are come with the title in json format.

Comment: As you have a python script already, why not do everything with python ?

Comment: @Philippe i think it would be a good idea. Earlier i thought it would be simpler with cli commands.

Comment: Also there is no reliable way to parse markup languages such as HTML with shell. HTML is the worst to parse because of its permissive evasive syntax. You'd better ask the site to have access to its data source via an API rather than trying to parse. HTML pages are for rendering only, they cannot convey data for processing.

Answer (score 0):

OP Here.

Both of the following commands are working for me:

```
curl -Lfs "https://motivatedsisters.com/2019/07/08/arabic-review-sr-rahat-basit/" | rg -o '<li>.*?href="(.*?)".*?</a> (.*?)<\/li>' -r 'echo $1 $(unescape_html "$2")' | bash | rg -o '(https?://\S+)\s(.*)' -r 'echo $1 $(unescape_html "$2")'  -r '{"url": "$1", "title": "$2"}' | jq -s '.'
```

and

```
curl -Lfs "https://motivatedsisters.com/2019/07/08/arabic-review-sr-rahat-basit/" | rg '<li>.*?href="(.*?)".*?</a> (.*?)<\/li>' -or '$1 $2' | while read -r link title; do echo "$link" "$(unescape_html "$title")"; done | rg -o '(https?://\S+)\s(.*)' -r '{"url": "$1", "title": "$2"}' | jq -s '.'
```